# validate input for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i haven`t form, just only input for html:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>name</p>
<input type="text" size="15" id="title"  placeholder="enter title" onclick="check(this)">
<p>description</p>
<textarea rows="7" cols="20" id="description"  placeholder="enter description"> </textarea>
<p>price</p>
<input type ="number" value="00.0" min="0" step="0.1" id="price"><br>
<button id="add_new_product" >Add new product</button><br>
<a href="catalog.html">All product</a>
</body>
```

I must validate this input on empty. 
my js file:

```
$(function(){

    $('#add_new_product').click(function(){

        var title = $("#title").val();
        var description = $("#description").val();
        var price = $("#price").val();

        $.ajax({url:'adres/add_new_product',type:'GET', data:{description:description,title:title, price:price},success:function(result){
    alert('Product was add!)');            }
        });

    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({url:'adres/all_products', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', success:function(result){
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            $('#list_of_products').append('<b>' + result[i].name + '</b><br>' + result[i].description + '</br><br>'+result[i].price+'<br><br>');}
    }});
});
```

Comment: Can you please post the attempts you've made yourself to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, You can call a javascript function while the new product button is clicked.

replace

```
<button id="add_new_product" >Add new product</button><br>
```

with

```
 <button id="add_new_product" onClick="javascript: validatefield()" >Add new product</button><br>
```

in validatefield() function you can validate your field.

Refer this , http://jsfiddle.net/NWWL4/19/

Comment: alert work, but product adds after alert about mistake

Comment: I must validate all fields where I get products. if will be return that in input is mistake,my ajax request are not working